# Where is tab "People"

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I have start to develop application for iPhone. Start do it with other people, add him in developer team in iTunesConnect. But they can't see our developer team in XCode. To fix that [original guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW1) say that I need invite user by `People` tab, but I can't see it in my account. What I do wrong?

I am owner of developer account. Team is personal as I know.

[image][image]

Is it possible by it account create team and develop like team?

Comment: What's your role? Agent? Admin? Member?

Comment: @Larme my role is Admin

Comment: @Larme obviously maybe I am `Agent`. I enter `people` after `#` instead overview end see that I am agent. Is it possible by it account create team and develop like team?

Comment: did it get solved

Comment: Not at all. I think I have no access to this feature. Maybe we need to by enterprise account or something like this.